# Applying an average across groups in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame of this form:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

# generate contrived data
df = pd.DataFrame({"Timestep" : np.arange(1000),
                   "Sensor Reading" : np.sin(np.arange(1000) * 2 * np.pi/100.0) + 0.1 * np.random.standard_normal(1000),
                   "Label" : np.repeat(np.arange(10), [96, 107, 95, 104, 97, 100, 105, 103, 100, 93])
                   })
plt.plot(df["Sensor Reading"])
plt.figure()
```

[image]

Essentially I have 10 *periods* identified by column "Label", each of which has *about* 100 noisy readings from a sensor.

I want to get an averaged signal by stacking/aligning each of the 10 periods (trimming to the shortest period) and getting an average value across each time-point. I can do this iteratively with this code:

```
grouped = df.groupby("Label")

# current method
grouplength = min(len(g) for k, g in grouped)
reference_result = np.zeros(grouplength)
for k, group in grouped:
    reference_result += group["Sensor Reading"][:grouplength]/len(grouped)
```

i.e. something that looks like this:

[image]

But I cannot work out how to use the [group by](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) functions (transform, apply, etc) to achieve the same result. How can I do this in a concise way using pandas?

(Please note: In the full application this is not a sine wave but is a measured physical response to a signal sent out at the start of each period. So I am *not* looking for a robust way to align the signals or to detect frequencies.)

Comment: Padding each group to the length of the longest one with zeros instead of trimming is also  OK, if that's easier to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this more efficiently using [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items) (new in 0.13):

```
grouplength = grouped.size().min()
cumcount = grouped.cumcount()
sub_df = df.loc[cumcount < grouplength, 'Sensor Reading']
```

Provided the index is unique, you can groupby the `cumcount` and take the mean:

```
reference_result = sub_df.groupby(cumcount).mean().values
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Could you explain why this method is more efficient? It would be helpful as I'm still learning my way around pandas.

Comment: @MrE one way to test is to use %timeit in ipython, you'll see it's faster esp. for bigger frames. The reason is because these methods are written in cython/numpy rather than pure python.

Comment: Yep I can see that it's faster with %timeit but it doesn't seem that `reset_index` uses pure Python either. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py), `reset_index` [ends up calling `np.arange`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/array.py). Anyway this is both fast and clear so thanks again and I'll mark as accepted!

Comment: @MrE it's the for loop which is slow, as is apply (to a lesser extent). Although it's possible this could be made faster!

Answer (score 2):

call `reset_index` method on every group:

```
avg = df.groupby("Label")["Sensor Reading"].apply(pd.Series.reset_index, drop=True).mean(level=1)
avg.plot(avg)
```

Comment: This answer gives a different result to the OP's reference_result. Can the reset_index be avoided with as_index=False ?

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it pads each group to the max length. It doesn't exactly reproduce the reference result but is also fine for my use case.